# SQL - Create view from multiple tables for different roles

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table named admin:

[image: link]

I have more 2 tables named images1, images2 with the following data:

[image: link]

Now, `admin1` should have all the privileges over table `images1`, `admin2` should have all the privileges over table `images2`. `admin1` can't make changes into `images2` and vice versa.

The `sadmin` should be able to view and edit, update the entire data, ie, data from `images1` and `images2`. How can I create a view for `sadmin`, `admin1` and `admin2`? I have tried union, but it is not producing the result. Here is my query for sadmin view.

```
CREATE VIEW sadmin_fullview SELECT * FROM image1 UNION SELECT * FROM image2;
```

Comment: '*I have tried union*' - Show us your attempt.

Comment: @Script47
CREATE VIEW sadmin_fullview SELECT * FROM image1 UNION SELECT * FROM image2;

Comment: @Script47 I have made changes into my question, kindly remove the downvote.

Comment: Down-vote removed, in the future please add all the information in the first place and please format your posts, I did some of it for you this time.